# How can I get \framezoom to work in evince?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing, zooming

The `\framezoom` feature of the `beamer` class is awesome, but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly in evince (and the TeXworks previewer). When clicking the zoom button, the viewer correctly jumps to the zoomed slide at the end of the presentation. However, clicking again doesn't bring you back to the original slide.

Now I did some research and this seems to be due to the fact that the "back" link tries to use the actual "go back to where I was" function of the PDF viewer. Adobe Reader has such a function, but evince obviously doesn't. You can test this for yourself: open the compiled PDF with Reader and use the PageDown keys to go to the first zoomed slide. If you click on the slide, you are not brought back to the unzoomed frame but to the page where you just were, in this case the one labeled "Slide 5".

More specifically, the culprit seems to be the `\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}` command in the definition of the `\beamer@framezoom` macro in `beamerbaseframesize.sty`.

Because this is not going to get fixed in evince before Tuesday, I'd like to know if there is any workaround. For example, placing a regular link (like `\ref`) over the zoomed picture or in a corner, so that one can reliably get back to the original slide.

Can this be done? Where would I place the label? I've never placed `hyperref`s manually with `beamer`, so I'm a bit clueless.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=myzoom]
    \framezoom<1><2>[border](0cm,0cm)(1cm,1cm)
    \framezoom<1><3>[border](2cm,0cm)(1cm,1cm)
    Some stuff which\\should be zoomed.
\end{frame}

\frame{Slide 2}
\frame{Slide 3}
\frame{Slide 4}
\frame{Slide 5}

\againframe<2->{myzoom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using another (non Adobe) viewer where the feature is implemented is not an option?

Comment: It might be, *if* one is available. For example PDF Xchange viewer also supports it. But on the other hand, one of the greatest advantages of PDF presentations over PPT/ODP is that they just work, because a PDF reader is installed on basically every computer. This advantage is lost when using vendor-specific extensions (okay, actually I don't know if this is part of the official PDF spec and evince just fails to implement it correctly, or if it's really a vendor-thing).

Comment: It works in Okular, if that's any help. (Which makes me think this probably is not too Adobe-specific.)